# How to return only items that occur in 2 sql select statemnts

Tags: php, sql

I have two different sql statements. `$sql` grabs all the items whose title matches a certain search text. `$cat_sql` grabs all the `category_items` that are in a certain category. An item has an ID. A `category_item` has a field called `item_id` which is a foreign key to IDs in the `items` table

```
...
mysqli setup code
...

$title = $_POST["title"];
$cat_id = $_POST["cat_id"];

$cat_sql = "SELECT * FROM category_items WHERE category_id = '".$cat_id."'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where title LIKE '%". $title ."%' Limit 70";

if (!$result_cat = $mysqli->query($cat_sql)) {
// The query failed. 
    echo "<h2 >ERROR</h2>";
    exit;
}

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
// The query failed. 
    echo "<h2 >ERROR</h2>";
    exit;
}
```

Then I display all items:

```
while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    include 'item_card.php';
}
```

Currently this just displays all items fetched in the `$sql` query. Is there some way to remove all items from `$result` that do not have their ID represented as an `item_id` in `$result_cat`?

**NOTE:**
I would strongly prefer not to do just combine both SELECT statements into a table join because the actual $sql and $cat_sql are not nearly as simple as I have represented here. Also, they vary depending on which if statement they are in.

My question is: given `$result` and `$result_cat`, can I remove items from $result?

**EDIT 1**
As suggested by comments I am making an array if item_ids then doing an in_array query. Progress thus far:

```
$result_cat_ids = [];
while ($cat_item = $result_cat->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result_cat_ids[] = $cat_item['item_id'];
}
```

**EDIT 2** Here is the working code following the suggestions in the comments

```
  if (in_array($item['id'], $result_cat_ids)) {
      include 'item_card.php';
  }
```

Comment: Store all the IDs from `$result_cat` into an array (`$result_cut_ids`). And then use `in_array()` like `if (!in_array($item['ID'], $result_cut_ids)) { .. }`. But i would prefer to combine the selects :-)

Comment: I would say; loop through `$result` as you are doing, then use the `in_array` method, with $result_cat` as the `haystack` and $item['category_id]` as the needle... while doing an  `IF` check.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use 'INTERSECT' sql clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN (SELECT item_id FROM category_items WHERE category_id = '".$cat_id."' INTERSECT SELECT id FROM items where title LIKE '%". $title ."%')";
```

This way, you can query for items that accomplish both conditions.

Note: I'm not using "limit 70" but you may add it as well.